# Slider: image optimization

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

For a large image slider as background on the page, would you download all images in a single file (css sprites)?
Or would it be better to load them one by one as the slider gives enough time to load the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load them one by one. This makes initial load quicker, and if a user navigates away from the page before all images are loaded, it saves bandwidth.

Image sprites are especially useful for small images (icons, backgrounds), of which the overhead of a http request is significant. For a large image, the overhead of the request itself is only a fraction of the download.